# How to identify a first occurence of a condition in python data frame and perform a calculation on it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, back-testing

I am really struggling to get a logic for this . I have data set called **Col** as shown below . I am using Python and Pandas

I want to set a new column called as "STATUS" . The logic is

a. When Col==0 , i will **Buy** . But this Buy will happen only when Col==0 is the first value in the data set or after the **Status** **Sell**. There cannot be two **Buy** values without a **Sell** in between

b. When Col<=-8 I will  **Sell**. But this will happen if there is a Buy preceding it in the Satus Column. There cannot be two **Sells** without a Buy in between them .

I have provided the example of how i want my output as. Any help is really appreciated

Here the raw data is in the column : **Col** and output i want is in **Status**

```html
  +-------+--------+
    |  Col  | Status |
    +-------+--------+
    | 0     | Buy    |
    | -1.41 | 0      |
    | 0     | 0      |
    | -7.37 | 0      |
    | -8.78 | Sell   |
    | -11.6 | 0      |
    | 0     | Buy    |
    | -5    | 0      |
    | -6.1  | 0      |
    | -8    | Sell   |
    | -11   | 0      |
    | 0     | Buy    |
    | 0     | 0      |
    | -9    | Sell   |
    +-------+--------+
```

Comment: kindly post the original dataframe. I assume what you currently have here is the expected output

Comment: The Column Col is the Data  Column i have and Status is the output

Comment: Besides of the problem you're describing here that is something I would handle inside the backtesting algorithm (assuming that is what you're trying to do). Therefore I would allow multiple buys/sells without sells/buys between them and just ignore them inside your backtesting logic.

Comment: Yes, it's a backtesting algorithm . I tried using multiple Buys and Sells , but the only way to eliminate them appears like a string concatenation and using a regex. i can't think of any other way

Answer (score 0):

Took me some time.
Relies on the following property : 
the last order you can see from now, even if you chose not to send it, is always the last decision that you took. (Otherwise it would have been sent.)

```
df['order'] = (df['order'] == 0).astype(int) - (df['order'] <= -8).astype(int)
orders_no_filter = df.loc[df['order'] != 0, 'order']
possible = (orders_no_filter != orders_no_filter.shift(1))
df['order'] = df['order'] * possible.reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
```